# How to convert json file to dictionary c# without any frameworks. .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-3.5

I have json few json file with text localization data. i want to convert this json file to dictionary. I couldnt use json.net or other frameworks. How can i do this?

{
   main_menu_ng:"new game",
   main_menu_lg:"load game",
   ....

}

Comment: Read file, split it by `,` and save. Just try

Comment: I think your question answered here like your want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539454/10120770

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

JavaScriptSerializer for this.

```
List<Class> list = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Class>>(jsonString);
```

you need to use

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<> for that:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(yourFileName);
yourDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39539454/10120770